# How can embed Youtube Play Button and also open custom URL Link

Tags: javascript, java, php, html, ios

i want to create one my custom URL link with Youtube play button, when any one come on my site and when he play youtube video then one url link open for external page.

Answer (score 0):

You could just mock the look, then just wrap the whole thing in a link.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: clip;
}

.wrap .thumb {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L_LUpnjgPso/hqdefault.jpg')
}

.wrap .thumb:hover .ytp-large-play-button-bg {
  transition: fill 0.1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1), fill-opacity 0.1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  fill: #f00;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.wrap .thumb button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 68px;
  height: 48px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: opacity 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  z-index: 63;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  cursor: inherit;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="thumb">
      <button aria-label="play">
        <svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 68 48" width="100%">
          <path
            class="ytp-large-play-button-bg"
            d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"
            fill="#212121"
            fill-opacity="0.8"
          />
          <path d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34" fill="#fff" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```